# Slow query times on AWS RDS but not on DigitalOcean LAMP

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, digital-ocean

I have a database dump and MySQL query that is the same across three environments, but it is extremely slow on AWS, and I'd like to find out why.

Query runs 15s ~ 30s on AWS RDS but 8ms ~ 12ms on DigitalOcean LAMP. (Control experiment: Local MAMP stack runs 8s ~ 10s).

How is this possible that DigitalOcean LAMP stack is running the same query in ms?

Backstory: I migrated from DigitalOcean to AWS RDS. I am super shocked at the query speeds. I can't figure out why.

Note: Using T2.micro RDS instance. Have also tested with M4.2xLarge RDS instance. Query times are the same.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT `t`.`col1` AS `t0_c0`,
       `t`.`col2` AS `t0_c1`,
       `t`.`col3` AS `t0_c2`,
       `t`.`col4` AS `t0_c3`,
       `t`.`col5` AS `t0_c4`,
       `t`.`col6` AS `t0_c5`,
       `t`.`col7` AS `t0_c6`,
       `t`.`col8` AS `t0_c7`,
       `t`.`col9` AS `t0_c8`,
       `t`.`col10` AS `t0_c9`,
       `t`.`col11` AS `t0_c10`,
       `t`.`col12` AS `t0_c11`,
       `t`.`col13` AS `t0_c12`,
       `t`.`col14` AS `t0_c13`,
       `t`.`col15` AS `t0_c14`,
       `t`.`col16` AS `t0_c15`,
       `t`.`col17` AS `t0_c16`,
       `t`.`col18` AS `t0_c17`,
       `t`.`col19` AS `t0_c18`,
       `t`.`col20` AS `t0_c19`,
       `t`.`col21` AS `t0_c20`,
       `t`.`col22` AS `t0_c21`,
       `t`.`col23` AS `t0_c22`,
       `t`.`col24` AS `t0_c23`,
       `t`.`col25` AS `t0_c24`,
       `t`.`col26` AS `t0_c25`,
       `t`.`col27` AS `t0_c26`,
       `t`.`col28` AS `t0_c27`,
       `t`.`col29` AS `t0_c28`,
       `t`.`col30` AS `t0_c29`,
       `t`.`col31` AS `t0_c30`,
       `t`.`col32` AS `t0_c31`,
       `t`.`col33` AS `t0_c32`,
       `t`.`col34` AS `t0_c33`,
       `t`.`col35` AS `t0_c34`,
       `t`.`col36` AS `t0_c35`,
       `t`.`col37` AS `t0_c36`,
       `t`.`col38` AS `t0_c37`,
       `t`.`col39` AS `t0_c38`,
       `t`.`col40` AS `t0_c39`,
       `t`.`col41` AS `t0_c40`,
       `t`.`col42` AS `t0_c41`,
       `t`.`col43` AS `t0_c42`,
       `t`.`col44` AS `t0_c43`,
       `t`.`col45` AS `t0_c44`,
       `t`.`col46` AS `t0_c45`,
       `t`.`col47` AS `t0_c46`,
       `t`.`col48` AS `t0_c47`,
       `t`.`col49` AS `t0_c48`,
       COUNT(exactTagMatch.id) AS exactMatches,
       COUNT(tags.id) AS matches,
       `vendor`.`col1` AS `t1_c0`,
       `vendor`.`col2` AS `t1_c1`,
       `vendor`.`col3` AS `t1_c2`,
       `vendor`.`col4` AS `t1_c3`,
       `vendor`.`col5` AS `t1_c4`,
       `vendor`.`col6` AS `t1_c5`,
       `vendor`.`col7` AS `t1_c6`,
       `vendor`.`col8` AS `t1_c7`,
       `vendor`.`col9` AS `t1_c8`,
       `vendor`.`col10` AS `t1_c9`,
       `vendor`.`col11` AS `t1_c10`,
       `vendor`.`col12` AS `t1_c11`,
       `vendor`.`col13` AS `t1_c12`,
       `vendor`.`col14` AS `t1_c13`,
       `vendor`.`col15` AS `t1_c14`,
       `vendor`.`col16` AS `t1_c15`,
       `vendor`.`col17` AS `t1_c16`,
       `vendor`.`col18` AS `t1_c17`,
       `vendor`.`col19` AS `t1_c18`,
       `vendor`.`col20` AS `t1_c19`,
       `vendor`.`col21` AS `t1_c20`,
       `vendor`.`col22` AS `t1_c21`,
       `vendor`.`col23` AS `t1_c22`,
       `vendor`.`col24` AS `t1_c23`,
       `vendor`.`col25` AS `t1_c24`,
       `vendor`.`col26` AS `t1_c25`,
       `vendor`.`col27` AS `t1_c26`,
       `vendor`.`col28` AS `t1_c27`,
       `tags`.`col1` AS `t2_c0`,
       `tags`.`col2` AS `t2_c1`,
       `tags`.`col3` AS `t2_c2`,
       `tags`.`col4` AS `t2_c3`,
       `tags`.`col5` AS `t2_c4`,
       `tags`.`col6` AS `t2_c5`,
       `tags`.`col7` AS `t2_c6`,
       `tags`.`col8` AS `t2_c7`,
       `tags`.`col9` AS `t2_c8`,
       `tags`.`col10` AS `t2_c9`,
       `tags`.`col11` AS `t2_c10`,
       `tags`.`col12` AS `t2_c11`
FROM `table1` `t`
LEFT JOIN table3 AS exactTagMatch ON exactTagMatch.col1 = 1545
AND exactTagMatch.col1 = t.col1
LEFT OUTER JOIN `table2` `vendor` ON (`t`.`col1`=`vendor`.`id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `table3` `tags_tags` ON (`t`.`col1`=`tags_tags`.`col1`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `table3` `tags` ON (`tags`.`id`=`tags_tags`.`col1`)
WHERE (((((t.col2 LIKE '%search query%')
          OR (vendor.col2 LIKE '%search query%'))
         OR (tags.col1 IN ('1386',
                         '1407',
                         '1408',
                         '1409',
                         '1410',
                         '1411',
                         '1416',
                         '1418',
                         '1512',
                         '1519',
                         '1528',
                         '1545',
                         '1583',
                         '1584',
                         '1585',
                         '1586',
                         '1604',
                         '1605')))
        AND (t.col2='active'))
       AND (t.col3='0'))
GROUP BY t.col1
ORDER BY exactMatches DESC,
         matches DESC,
         t.col5 DESC LIMIT 12;
```

**MySQL Plan: AWS RDS (Slow)**

```
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type   | possible_keys                   | key                     | key_len | ref                   | rows  | Extra                                                  |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t             | ref    | PRIMARY,activity_status_premium | activity_status_premium | 2       | const,const           |   594 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | exactTagMatch | ALL    | NULL                            | NULL                    | NULL    | NULL                  | 24434 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vendor        | eq_ref | PRIMARY                         | PRIMARY                 | 4       | ebdb.t.vendor_id      |     1 | NULL                                                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tags_tags     | ALL    | NULL                            | NULL                    | NULL    | NULL                  | 24434 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tags          | eq_ref | PRIMARY                         | PRIMARY                 | 4       | ebdb.tags_tags.tag_id |     1 | Using where                                            |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

**MySQL Plan: DigitalOcean (Fast)**

```
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type   | possible_keys           | key                     | key_len | ref                           | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t             | ref    | activity_status_premium | activity_status_premium | 2       | const,const                   |   590 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | exactTagMatch | ALL    | NULL                    | NULL                    | NULL    | NULL                          | 32473 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vendor        | eq_ref | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY                 | 4       | db.t.vendor_id      |     1 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tags_tags     | ALL    | NULL                    | NULL                    | NULL    | NULL                          | 32473 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tags          | eq_ref | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY                 | 4       | db.tags_tags.tag_id |     1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

---

Here is a comparison between the MySQL versions:

**MySQL Version: AWS RDS (Slow)**

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.27                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| version                 | 5.6.27                   |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

**MySQL Version: DigitalOcean (Fast)**

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.5.44                  |
| protocol_version        | 10                      |
| slave_type_conversions  |                         |
| version                 | 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                  |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu        |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

---

Here is a comparison between the .cnf files: https://www.diffnow.com/?report=ze4m0

*Note: Had to use external link because body exceeded character count*

---

#### Update

Just ran more tests. On DigitalOcean, the first time i run the query it took 14s. Thereafter it runs in in ms. I believe there is some sort of caching/indexing going on there. Would like to find out what could result in this.

Comment: Can we see the query in question and an explain plan for it, from all of your environments?

Comment: It sounds like your local machine is very slow as well - 8s down to 8ms is an impressive speed-up!

Comment: @halfer Thanks for helping out, have updated as you asked

Comment: Perhaps in a legible form, in fact.  Understand that DO uses all solid state devices.

Comment: Okay moment please will use mysql shell to output the info. Running SSD on RDS too.

Comment: @TGray Have updated the explain outputs, what do you think?

Comment: I know this is painstaking, but can you give us the versions of MySQL from both servers and the my.cnf files as well?  The optimizer output is similar, but enough different that it is a bit confusing.  In both cases, the full table scans for counts are going to be destructive.  I have seen very strange behaviors (things like this) because of SAN routings as well.  Given the nature of AWS and DO, you can't probably ascertain if that is an issue.  It does "feel" a bit like an I/O problem though.

Comment: @TGray No pain at all, thanks for info. Give me a moment to update the information required.

Comment: Thanks for the queries and explain plan, please [make them readable](http://sqlformat.org/) next time!

Comment: I'm grasping at straws - there doesn't seem to be anything immediately apparent.  query_cache_size is 1/16th (or so) the size on AWS as it is on DO (there are sorts going on in your explain which could be a problem) 1048576 AWS, 16777216 DO.  On the other hand AWS innodb_buffer_pool_size is 4 times larger. Not much else is popping out. A couple of interesting articles:  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71130 and https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/02/18/is-mysql-5-6-slower-than-mysql-5-5/ and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66406/slower-queries-after-upgrade-from-mysql-5-5-to-mysql-5-6.

Comment: @TGray thanks for your help, problem was due to query cache as highlighted by Rich below

Comment: Pleased you fixed it! Note that I have restored the SQL query, since the explain plans are directly related to it. Whilst it turns out that the problem was due to a configuration switch, we do not modify questions retrospectively once the answer is discovered - the point of Stack Overflow is to preserve questions and answers so that future readers may learn from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySql 5.6+, the query cache is disabled by default. In your my.cnf files you can see that by looking for "query_cache_type" - you'll see it's OFF on RDS, but not on the DO db.

I'd bet that if you run the query for the first time on DO it will be a similar speed - no other conf change is likely to result in such dramatic differences.

As the cache is off now by default, you should read up on the reasons for that change - it's your call if you need it or not, but just note that it was disabled deliberately!